# How can I push text log files into Cloud Logging?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automationanywhere

I have an application (Automation Anywhere A360) that whenever I want to log something with the app it will log it into a txt/csv file. I run a process in Automation Anywhere that is run in 10 bot runners (Windows VMs) concurrently (so each bot runner is going to log what is going on locally)

My intention is that instead of having sepparate log files for each bot runner, **I'd like to have a centralized place where I store all the logs (i.e. Cloud Logging).**

I know that this can be accomplished using Python, Java, etc. However, if every time I need to log something into Cloud Logging I invoke a Python script, even though that does the job, it takes around 2-3 seconds (I think this is a bit slow) connecting to gcp client and logging in (taking in this first step most of the time).

How woud you guys tackle this?

Comment: You may want to try configuring [Ops Agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent) to collect the logs directly. The agent runs on (Windows) VMs and can be [configured](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/configuration#windows) to collect logs from most (!?) apps. Log processing is handled by [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/)

Comment: That is a great solution for metrics related to CPU, Memory, Network and so on (correct me if I'm wrong please). Thing is that what I would like to move to Cloud Logging is application related logs (e.g. in Automation Anywhere program/bot whenever something meaningful happens logs it in a txt/csv file)

Comment: Ops Agent is for application logs too ([link](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/configuration#logging-config)). It comes preconfigured to parse logs from a set of standard apps but you can configure it to parse logs from pretty much anything.

Comment: Thing is that I cannot install it on a local machine (or VM outside GCP)

Comment: Aha! Is it documented that it's not possible to install off-Cloud? Generally Google's agents will run anywhere but will need some additional config for auth etc. to work. But, it appears you want a different solution. In that case, you will need to write your own agent|sidecar. It can leverage Google's Cloud Logging client libraries to add log entries to the service. You may want to consider combining your solution with fluentd or fluentbit ([link](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/about/fluentd-and-fluent-bit)) since these can do a bunch of the legwork for you.

Comment: It is documented in their official page a explicit solution for on-premises systems and it's named"BindPlane" [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/blue-medora/collecting-on-prem-hybrid). Nonetheless I think that your solution might be a bit more customizable, but it is what it is....

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I am looking for is something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/blue-medora/collecting-on-prem-hybrid). It is named BindPlane and it can collect log data from on-premises and hybrid infra and send it to GCP monitoring/logging stack

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may (still) concern: You could use fluentd to forward logs to pubSub and from there to a Cloud Logging bucket.

https://flugel.it/infrastructure-as-code/how-to-setup-fluentd-to-retrieve-logs-send-them-to-gcp-pub-sub-to-finally-push-them-to-elasticsearch/

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at this, thank you!